# Android services - Sockets and streaming from one service to another on another phone

Tags: android, sockets, service

To put things simply, I'm writing a video chat application that's supposed to connect say, two Android phones. So far, I've managed to negotiate interactions between clients, until the point I've reached the part where I'm supposed to do the streaming of video (and later audio) data between the clients.

The problem is as follows:

I am trying to implement a service that will, once a person has decided to contact someone, be started from a ChatActivity, and that will negotiate streaming between the two clients, making the sockets and the data going between them completely independent of the events going on within the ChatActivity, except for the moment the conversation is over, where the activity is terminated for good, and with it the service.

However, my concern comes from the point that if the service terminates the sockets mid-conversation, I have the problem of having to renegotiate streaming between client and client.
As is probably obvious, my knowledge of android services is limited, at best, and any advice on the subject is welcome

My questions are:

- Is it doable to create a service that will, bar unexpected crashes due to outside influences, keep such a connection active and running regardless of how many times the activity that displays the video from the streaming (ChatActivity) is destroyed and created?
- Should I be going with a bound service or a started service for this, or some hybrid of the two?
- If I were to somehow create a pair usable stream of video data from the service, one via internet connection other via camera, would I be able to send them back to the activity, and keep reconnecting them to the components, regardless of how many times they get destroyed and created during the lifecycle?
- Despite my efforts, I haven't managed to find any examples of anything similar, if anyone has come across code that does some similar socket/service juggling, I'd be most grateful for directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it doable to create a service that will, bar unexpected crashes due to outside influences, keep such a connection active and running regardless of how many times the activity that displays the video from the streaming (ChatActivity) is destroyed and created?

The `Service` lifecycle, if started via `startService()`, is independent of the lifecycle of any of the activities. Activities can come and go, but a service can stick around for a while.

> Should I be going with a bound service or a started service for this, or some hybrid of the two?

You will need to use `startService()` if you intend for your `Service` to run without any activities around.

> If I were to somehow create a pair usable stream of video data from the service, one via internet connection other via camera, would I be able to send them back to the activity, and keep reconnecting them to the components, regardless of how many times they get destroyed and created during the lifecycle?

That's impossible for me to answer, without a complete description of what "a pair usable stream of video data" means.

That being said, you will probably want to consider an event bus like Square's Otto or greenrobot's EventBus, as they both have support for the UI layer receiving events on the fly (e.g., service just establishes communications) and retrieving on demand the last-sent event (e.g., activity needs to reconnect to the last stream).

Comment: My apologies, I've only now noticed the typo that made it not make any sense.
Under "a pair usable stream of video " I meant making two video streams in one form or another, one from the camera preview, other acquired via the net, and making them both available to the UI, so I could display them.
The first statement makes perfect sense, and now I know what I'm going to do with it.